# PhpStorm freezes on startup

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, windows-10, phpstorm

I'm using Windows 10 64 bit, latest version of PhpStorm, it keeps freezing/hanging on startup.

Here's `idea.log` file, is there any obvious plugin I should remove? Is it caused by Material Theme? I can't see any plugin causing the issue

```
2018-10-18 15:35:20,735 [  17187]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - PhpStorm 2018.2.4  Build #PS-182.4505.42 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,735 [  17187]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,735 [  17187]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,735 [  17187]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,735 [  17187]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - OS: Windows 10 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,735 [  17187]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Last Action:  
2018-10-18 15:35:20,866 [  17318]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [Plugin: com.jetbrains.php] 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [Plugin: com.jetbrains.php]
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.convertStub(ActionManagerImpl.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.getAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.preloadActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:1266)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader.preload(ActionPreloader.java:32)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.a(Preloader.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.a(Preloader.java:72)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:226)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$100(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:26)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:199)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:229)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.intellij.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:160)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:427)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.convertStub(ActionManagerImpl.java:141)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:419)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jetbrains.php.PhpIcons
    at com.jetbrains.php.actions.PhpNewBaseAction.<init>(PhpNewBaseAction.java:50)
    at com.jetbrains.php.actions.PhpNewClassAction.<init>(PhpNewClassAction.java:18)
    ... 25 more
2018-10-18 15:35:20,867 [  17319]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - PhpStorm 2018.2.4  Build #PS-182.4505.42 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,868 [  17320]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,868 [  17320]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,868 [  17320]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,868 [  17320]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - OS: Windows 10 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,868 [  17320]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Last Action:  
2018-10-18 15:35:20,871 [  17323]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/codeStyle/AddNewSectionRule.svg' with '/icons/codeStyle/AddNewSectionRule.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,871 [  17323]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/general/gearPlain.svg' with '/icons/general/gearPlain.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,879 [  17331]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/addToWatch.svg' with '/icons/debugger/addToWatch.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,880 [  17332]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/attachToProcess.svg' with '/icons/debugger/attachToProcess.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,881 [  17333]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/general/filter.svg' with '/icons/general/filter.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/console.png' with '/icons/debugger/console.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/console.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/console.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_array.png' with '/icons/debugger/db_array.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/db_array.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/db_array.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_db_object.png' with '/icons/debugger/db_db_object.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/db_db_object.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/db_db_object.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_dep_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_dep_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_dep_line_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_dep_line_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_dep_method_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_dep_method_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_disabled_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_disabled_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_disabled_breakpoint_process.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_disabled_breakpoint_process.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_disabled_exception_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_disabled_exception_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_disabled_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_disabled_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_disabled_method_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_disabled_method_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,882 [  17334]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_method_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_method_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_dep_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_dep_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_dep_line_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_dep_line_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,883 [  17335]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_dep_method_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_dep_method_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_disabled_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_disabled_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_disabled_breakpoint_process.png' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_disabled_breakpoint_process.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/db_muted_disabled_breakpoint_process.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/db_muted_disabled_breakpoint_process.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_disabled_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_disabled_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_disabled_method_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_disabled_method_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_exception_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_invalid_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,884 [  17336]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_method_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_method_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,885 [  17337]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,885 [  17337]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,885 [  17337]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_muted_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_muted_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_no_suspend_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_no_suspend_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_no_suspend_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_no_suspend_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_no_suspend_method_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_no_suspend_method_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_obsolete.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_obsolete.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_set_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_set_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_primitive.png' with '/icons/debugger/db_primitive.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/db_primitive.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/db_primitive.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_set_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_set_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_set_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_set_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_verified_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_verified_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_verified_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_verified_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_verified_method_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_verified_method_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_verified_no_suspend_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_verified_no_suspend_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_verified_no_suspend_field_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_verified_no_suspend_field_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_verified_no_suspend_method_breakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/db_verified_no_suspend_method_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/db_verified_warning_breakpoint.png' with '/icons/debugger/db_verified_warning_breakpoint.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/db_verified_warning_breakpoint.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/db_verified_warning_breakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,886 [  17338]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/evaluateExpression.svg' with '/icons/debugger/evaluateExpression.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/frame.png' with '/icons/debugger/frame.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/frame.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/frame.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/killProcess.svg' with '/icons/debugger/killProcess.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/LambdaBreakpoint.svg' with '/icons/debugger/LambdaBreakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/MultipleBreakpoints.svg' with '/icons/debugger/MultipleBreakpoints.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/muteBreakpoints.svg' with '/icons/debugger/muteBreakpoints.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/general/add.svg' with '/icons/general/add.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/overhead.png' with '/icons/debugger/overhead.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/overhead.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/overhead.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/question_badge.png' with '/icons/debugger/question_badge.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/question_badge.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/question_badge.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,887 [  17339]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/restoreLayout.svg' with '/icons/debugger/restoreLayout.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/showCurrentFrame.svg' with '/icons/debugger/showCurrentFrame.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/smartStepInto.svg' with '/icons/debugger/smartStepInto.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/frame.png' with '/icons/debugger/frame.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/frame.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/frame.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/threadAtBreakpoint.png' with '/icons/debugger/threadAtBreakpoint.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/threadAtBreakpoint.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/threadAtBreakpoint.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/threadCurrent.png' with '/icons/debugger/threadCurrent.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/threadCurrent.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/threadCurrent.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/threadFrozen.png' with '/icons/debugger/threadFrozen.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/threadFrozen.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/threadFrozen.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/threadGroup.png' with '/icons/debugger/threadGroup.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/threadGroup.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/threadGroup.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/threadGroupCurrent.png' with '/icons/debugger/threadGroupCurrent.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/threadGroupCurrent.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/threadGroupCurrent.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/threadRunning.png' with '/icons/debugger/threadRunning.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/threadRunning.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/threadRunning.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/threads.svg' with '/icons/debugger/threads.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/threadSuspended.png' with '/icons/debugger/threadSuspended.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/threadSuspended.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/threadSuspended.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/toolConsole.png' with '/icons/debugger/toolConsole.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,888 [  17340]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/toolConsole.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/toolConsole.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,889 [  17341]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/value.png' with '/icons/debugger/value.png' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,889 [  17341]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/icons/debugger/value.png' with 'jar:file:/C:/Users/user-pc/.PhpStorm2018.2/config/plugins/Material%20Theme/lib/material-theme-jetbrains-2.9.2.jar!/icons/debugger/value.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,889 [  17341]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/viewBreakpoints.svg' with '/icons/debugger/viewBreakpoints.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,889 [  17341]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/watch.svg' with '/icons/debugger/watch.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,889 [  17341]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/debugger/watch.svg' with '/icons/debugger/watch.svg' 
2018-10-18 15:35:20,956 [  17408]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader took 2873 ms 
2018-10-18 15:35:21,267 [  17719]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === calculateInitStatus.value: JBA_NOT_CONNECTED === 
2018-10-18 15:35:21,268 [  17720]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === End.updateInitStatus === 
2018-10-18 15:35:21,550 [  18002]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 24 project components initialized in 220 ms 
2018-10-18 15:35:21,554 [  18006]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader took 597 ms 
2018-10-18 15:35:21,883 [  18335]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader took 329 ms 
2018-10-18 15:35:21,889 [  18341]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.actions.GotoClassPresentationUpdater took 5 ms 
2018-10-18 15:37:11,739 [ 128191]   INFO - m.intellij.ui.mac.touchbar.NST - OS doesn't support touchbar, skip nst loading
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks similar to https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/issues/964, please try updated plugin version from https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/issues/964#issuecomment-429136253.

If it doesn't help, try removing **Material Theme UI** plugin.